# Query for calculating duration between two different logs in Splunk

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

As part of my requirements, I have to calculate the duration between two different logs using Splunk query.
For example:

**Log 2:**
    *2020-04-22 13:12  ADD request received ID : 123*

**Log 1 :**
    *2020-04-22 12:12  REMOVE request received ID : 122*

The common String between two logs is " request received ID :" and unique strings between two logs are "ADD", "REMOVE". And the expected output duration is 1 hour.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `transaction` command, https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/Transaction

Assuming you have the field `ID` extracted, you can do

```
index=* | transaction ID
```

This will automatically produce a field called `duration`, which is the time between the first and last event with the same `ID`

Answer (score 2):

While `transaction` *will* work, it's ***very*** inefficient

This `stats` should show you what you're looking for (presuming the fields are already extracted):

```
(index=ndxA OR index=ndxB) ID=* ("ADD" OR "REMOVE")
| stats min(_time) as when_added max(_time) as when_removed by ID
| eval when_added=strftime(when_added,"%c"), when_removed(when_removed,"%c")
```

If you *don't* already have fields extracted, you'll need to modify thusly (remove the "`\D$`" in the regex if the ID value isn't at the end of the line):

```
(index=ndxA OR index=ndxB) ("ADD" OR "REMOVE")
| rex field=_raw "ID \s+:\s+(?<ID>\d+)\D$"
| stats min(_time) as when_added max(_time) as when_removed by ID
| eval when_added=strftime(when_added,"%c"), when_removed(when_removed,"%c")
```